# Logout SSL (JBoss AS 7.1, JDK 1.6 e JSF 2)

Tags: jsf, authentication, ssl, jboss, servlet-filters

Good morning.

I have a problem when I try to perform logout in the authenticated system via a digital certificate.

To better describe the problem is as follows:

The browser presented the certificates for authentication check box, selecting and providing the PIN for the certificate selected the system performs login normally. The problem is when the user triggers the logout button, it invalidates the session and redirects to the login screen again. However when the user clicks the button that redirects to a restricted area the browser should resubmit the certificate selection box, but the same goes direct, using the certificate information selected in the previous login.

If we stop the server or close and open the browser it will prompt the choice of certificate again.

**standalone.xml:**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" redirect-port="8443"/>
        <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
            <ssl key-alias="localhost" verify-client="true"/>
        </connector>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
            <alias name="example.com"/>
        </virtual-server>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Authentication X509Certificate Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>br.gov.sp.sefin.desif.security.servlet.AuthX509CertificateFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Authentication X509Certificate Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>pages/*</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

**Filter authentication *AuthX509CertificateFilter* :**

```
public class AuthX509CertificateFilter implements Filter {

    private static final String MS_005 = "MS_005";
    private static final String URI_DEFINIR_IF = "/internet/pages/home.xhtml";

    private Principal authenticatedUser;

    @Inject
    private RepresentanteBO representanteBO;

    @Inject
    private InstituicaoFinanceiraBO instituicaoFinanceiraBO;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        Object attrSessionValid = req.getSession().getAttribute("sessionValid");
        Object attrSessionAuthenticated = req.getSession().getAttribute("authenticated");
        Object attrSessionInstituicaoFinanceira = req.getSession().getAttribute("instituicaoFinanceiraInternet");
        Boolean sessionValid = (Boolean) (attrSessionValid != null ? attrSessionValid : Boolean.FALSE);
        Boolean sessionAuthenticated = (Boolean) (attrSessionAuthenticated != null ? attrSessionAuthenticated : Boolean.FALSE);
        if(!sessionValid || (URI_DEFINIR_IF.equals(req.getRequestURI()) && attrSessionInstituicaoFinanceira == null)) {
            X509Certificate certs[] = (X509Certificate[] )req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
            if(certs != null) {
                X509Certificate t = (X509Certificate) certs[0];
                Principal subjectDN = t.getSubjectDN();
                authenticatedUser = subjectDN;
                sessionAuthenticated = validarAutenticacao(subjectDN, req, resp);                        
                chain.doFilter(new HttpServletRequestWrapper(req) {
                    @Override
                    public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
                        return authenticatedUser;
                    }
                }, response);
            }
        } else {
            Principal userPrincipal = req.getUserPrincipal();
            if(userPrincipal != null) {
                sessionAuthenticated = validarAutenticacao(userPrincipal, req, resp);
            }
            chain.doFilter(new HttpServletRequestWrapper(req) {
                @Override
                public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
                    return authenticatedUser;
                }
            }, response);
        }

        if(!resp.isCommitted() && !sessionAuthenticated) {
            Object attribute = req.getSession().getAttribute("cpfCnpj");
            if(attribute != null)
                req.getSession().setAttribute(MS_005, MessagePtBrUtil.recupera(MS_005, UtilFormatter.formatarCPF((String) attribute)));
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("../login.xhtml");
            dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
        }
    }


    public void atualizarDadosDeSessao(HttpServletRequest req, Boolean sessionValid, Boolean sessionAuthenticated) {
        req.getSession().setAttribute("sessionValid", sessionValid);
        req.getSession().setAttribute("authenticated", sessionAuthenticated);
    }

    public Boolean validarAutenticacao(Principal userPrincipal, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Boolean sessionValid = Boolean.TRUE;
        Boolean sessionAuthenticated = Boolean.TRUE;
        String[] cn = userPrincipal.getName().split(",");
        String cpfCnpj = cn[0].split(":")[1];
        req.getSession().setAttribute("cpfCnpj", cpfCnpj);
        BigInteger raizCnpj = new BigInteger(cpfCnpj.substring(0, 8));
        if(cpfCnpj.length() == 14 && instituicaoFinanceiraBO.verificarInstituicaoFinanceiraRaizCnpj(raizCnpj)) {
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("../pages/home.xhtml");
            dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
        } else {
            BigInteger cpf = new BigInteger(cpfCnpj);
            if(representanteBO.verificarRepresentanteInstituicaoFinanceira(cpf)) {
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("../pages/autenticarusuario/definirInstituicaoFinanceira.xhtml?cpf="+cpf);
                dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
            } else { // não tem instituição financeira vinculada ao CPF
                sessionValid = Boolean.FALSE; sessionAuthenticated = Boolean.FALSE;
            }
        }
        atualizarDadosDeSessao(req, sessionValid, sessionValid);
        return sessionValid && sessionAuthenticated;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

**Logout method:**

```
public void sair() {
    ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    this.inserirLogAuditoriaLogout();
    context.invalidateSession();

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getRequest();

    request.getSession().setAttribute("sessionValid", Boolean.FALSE);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("authenticated", Boolean.FALSE);

    try {
        request.logout();
        context.redirect("/internet/login.xhtml");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        new IOException();
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've tried using some javascript solutions to perform the cleaning of the certificate for authentication data stored in the browser. Example:

```
window.crypto.logout();

document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache");



function logOut()
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttp.timeout = 2000; // 2 seconds

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
        {
            console.log("status: "+xmlHttp.status);
            console.log("response: '"+xmlHttp.responseText+"'");
        }
    };
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "/internet/login.xhtml", true);
    xmlHttp.send();
}
```

But did not work.

Please if anyone has been there and succeeded in solve it present your solution.

I hope I can have been clear in the description of the problem. I am available to best describes it.

I thank you so much attention.